# Why can't I transfer ether in contract?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am deploying a contract to Ethereum EVM environment and using `Ropsten` test network. It sends 1 ether to another account which is passed from the method paratemter.

After deploy, I set the target account's address `0xAb8483F64d9C6d1EcF9b849Ae677dD3315835cb2` when call `transfer` method. But I see below error:

```
transact to Leger.transfer errored: VM error: revert.
    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Reason provided by the contract: "Transfer failed.".
Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

My account has 99 ethers and why I got above error?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.7.4;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract Leger {

    address payable owner;

    constructor(){
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function transfer(address payable _recipient) public payable {
        
        bool success = _recipient.send(1);
        require(success, "Transfer failed.");
    }


    function getBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
        return owner.balance;
    }
    

}
```

Comment: 1) On which network are you deploying the contract? Remix VM emulator,  Ropsten, ... 2) Are you passing any `value` while executing the `transfer()` function? ... Just a note: `send(1)` sends 1 wei (the smallest unit of ETH), not 1 ETH.

Comment: I am using Ropsten testing network. And in the code, I use `_recipient.send(1);` and I expect 1 means 1 ether. Do I need to specify other unit parameter in this function?

Answer (score 0):

If you're sending 1 ETH then provide 1*10^18 which is equals to 1000000000000000000wei.

And I'm not that experienced but I think you have to create some Tokens first to exchange it on your network using ETH.